# ApexCharts resizing issue with Angular 17

Tags: apexcharts, angular17

I have a graph using Apx Chart in an angular 17 application.
I use the following versions:

```
"@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
"apexcharts": "^3.45.1",
```

I actually have static data for test purpose. Data is hard coded In my component and i get the data onInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.chartOptions = getChartOptions(
    this.chartHeight,
    this.chartColor,
    this.strokeColor
  );
}
```

And finally I do call a simple function with data

```
function getChartOptions(
  chartHeight: string,
  chartColor: string,
  strokeColor: string
) {
  const labelColor = getCSSVariableValue('--bs-gray-500');
  const borderColor = getCSSVariableValue('--bs-gray-200');
  const color = getCSSVariableValue('--bs-' + chartColor);

  return {
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Net Profit',
        data: [30, 45, 32, 70, 40, 40, 40],
      },
    ],
    chart: {
      // redrawOnWindowResize: true,
      // redrawOnParentResize: true,
      fontFamily: 'inherit',
      type: 'area',
      height: chartHeight,
      toolbar: {
        show: false,
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      sparkline: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      dropShadow: {
        enabled: true,
        enabledOnSeries: undefined,
        top: 5,
        left: 0,
        blur: 3,
        color: strokeColor,
        opacity: 0.5,
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {},
    legend: {
      show: false,
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'solid',
      opacity: 0,
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth',
      show: true,
      width: 3,
      colors: [strokeColor],
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'],
      axisBorder: {
        show: false,
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: false,
      },
      labels: {
        show: false,
        style: {
          colors: labelColor,
          fontSize: '12px',
        },
      },
      crosshairs: {
        show: false,
        position: 'front',
        stroke: {
          color: borderColor,
          width: 1,
          dashArray: 3,
        },
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 80,
      labels: {
        show: false,
        style: {
          colors: labelColor,
          fontSize: '12px',
        },
      },
    },
    states: {
      normal: {
        filter: {
          type: 'none',
          value: 0,
        },
      },
      hover: {
        filter: {
          type: 'none',
          value: 0,
        },
      },
      active: {
        allowMultipleDataPointsSelection: false,
        filter: {
          type: 'none',
          value: 0,
        },
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
      },
      y: {
        formatter: function (val: number) {
          return '$' + val + ' thousands';
        },
      },
      marker: {
        show: false,
      },
    },
    colors: ['transparent'],
    markers: {
      colors: [color],
      strokeColors: [strokeColor],
      strokeWidth: 3,
    },
  };
}
```

On my HTML page, I pass values :

```
<apx-chart
    [series]="chartOptions.series"
    [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
    [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
    [yaxis]="chartOptions.yaxis"
    [dataLabels]="chartOptions.dataLabels"
    [stroke]="chartOptions.stroke"
    [legend]="chartOptions.legend"
    [fill]="chartOptions.fill"
    [states]="chartOptions.states"
    [tooltip]="chartOptions.tooltip"
    [colors]="chartOptions.colors"
    [markers]="chartOptions.markers"
    [plotOptions]="chartOptions.plotOptions"
  ></apx-chart>
```

My issue is that when i do resize my browser, the line graph disappear.
Before resizing:
[image]

After resizing:
[image]

I tried to add the following params:

```
redrawOnWindowResize: true,
redrawOnParentResize: true,
```

without success. I also tried using an host listener to reload the data:

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
onResize() {
  this.chartOptions = getChartOptions(
    this.chartHeight,
    this.chartColor,
    this.strokeColor
  );
  console.log(this.chartOptions);
}
```

All those approaches didn't work